# How to fix .htaccess problems

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I am trying to do it simple:

I want to remove .php extension from file for which I am using following code and it is working

```
#for hiding.php extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
############################-------- END ---------########################
```

Also I want to show a $_GET parameter on screen for which the link should be link this
localhost/123 which is representation of localhost/somepage.php?para=123
and for which I am using following code which is also working fine

```
    #for parameter Display
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*)$ somepage.php?para=$1
    ############################-------- END ---------########################
```

**Problem:** These codes are working fine when not written together in same `.htaccess` file. But when written together and When I have to access login page using localhost/login. .htaccess treat login as get parameter value. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to add [L] behind every RewriteRule, [L] Means stop if you find a match

Comment: Can you please give me an example..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ somepage.php?para=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: When I used localhost/login the it is displaying `login` on screen instead of redirecting to login.php page..

Comment: No it won't redirect but load content from `/login.php`.

Comment: what is location of this .htaccess? Is it in same dir as `login.php`?